# Spring Boot SLF4J Logging performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j

I have set log level info in my application now when I log messages with debug look  like

```
 logger.debug("Debug logs");
```

will the logging framework still construct log object internally? though debug message will not be printed as application log set to info level. If log object construct then I have to write

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Debug logs");
}
```

which looks like ugly code. Please suggest what I have to do in this case

Thank you

Comment: With slf4j you don't need to write `isDebugEnabled` both will be the same, probably the second will be slower, due to the addition if check.

Comment: But will slf4j construct a log object? The reason why I am saying is if log construct object it might be waste memory

Comment: The logger is created when you invoke the LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz) static method, not when you perform a logging operation.

Comment: Yes, but in order to log our message logger construct object, I guess internally.?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, the logger will be created anyway. What do you think `isDebugEnabled` is being called on.

Comment: My question is when I write like a logger.debug("Debug logs"); in this case, this message will be pass to the logging framework at that time. So will the logging framework create object in order to add logs? though framework first checks log level.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to wrap your logging statements with if statements as long as you use parameterized messages.

You should consider wrapping your logging statements only if they look like this and `getEntry()` is an expensive operation:

```java
logger.debug("The new entry is {}.", getEntry());
```

You can refer to the [SL4J logging performance documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance).